# Multiprocessing Process locking up forever in PyCharm

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pycharm

I've been having an odd issue with PyCharm and `subprocesses` created by the multiprocessing library locking up forever. I'm using Windows with Python 3.5. What I'm trying to do is:

1. Start a background thread to block on stdin (waiting for input)
2. Have the main thread check occasionally for input from stdin and then delegate the work to Python processes created using multiprocessing

However, I've found that newly created multiprocessing Processes lock up forever if and only if the following conditions are met:

1. I'm running the code via Pycharm (both the latest and older versions)
2. The background thread is blocking on stdin

Here's the simplest example I can create that reproduces the problem:

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import sys


def noop():
    pass


def consume():
    while True:
        sys.stdin.readline()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create a daemon thread to block on stdin
    thread = threading.Thread(target=consume, daemon=True)
    thread.start()

    # create a background process
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=noop)
    process.start()
```

I've Googled various combinations of "PyCharm stdin multiprocessing hang ..." and had no luck at finding an explanation, and I can't figure out why a thread of the main process blocking on stdin should ever cause a `subprocess` to also block/hang, let alone why it would only happen when running the script in PyCharm. The only think I can guess is that there might be some monkey-patching of either stdin or the multiprocessing library going on.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Can anyone explain to me why this only occurs in PyCharm, and how I can make it work regardless of the Python editor I'm using?

Comment: Same here... havent really found any particular solution for it..

Comment: I've found this can also happen intermittently in other non-Pycharm situations. There seems to be an intermittent issue with any kind of blocking I/O on stdin when launching processes using the multiprocessing library, but for some reason using PyCharm turns it from intermittent to reliably bad. In the end I gave up on using stdin as a means of communication with an external process and adopted named pipes instead.

Comment: Apparently there are some issues with `multiprocessing` in PyCharm: `_pickle.PicklingError` can result if running code in the interactive Python Console for PyCharm > 2021.1.3. See (1) [Multiprocessing package functions won't run in the interactive Python Console after upgrade to PyCharm 2021.2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50116) and (2) [Execution of multiprocessing.Pool gives an exception in Python Console](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20885)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was trying to do multiple API calls to fetch data from a remote server. I replaced multiprocessing dummy with ThreadPoolExecutor. It works in the same way as dummy.

Following is a short snippet of a running code to write the response to a json file:

```
    uids = [] # an array of the requisite parameters used in requests
    with open('flight_config.json', 'w') as f:
    futures = []
    for i in range(chunk_index, len(uids)):
        print('For uid[{}], fetching started:'.format(i))
        chunk_index += 1
        auth_token = get_header()
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=7) as executor:
            future_to_url = {executor.submit(fetch_response_from_api, uid=uid, auth_token=auth_token): uid for uid in
                             uids[i]}
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                result = future_to_url[future]
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                    print(data)
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (result, exc))
                else:
                    print('%r page is %d bytes' % (result, len(data)))
```