# Python proccess not start via block input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-multiprocessing

Minimal code for test. If clear # time.sleep(0.5) to add function not started in other proccess.How do without time.sleep

```py
import multiprocessing
import time


def add(counter):
    while 1:
        print(counter.value)
        counter.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=add, args=(counter,))
    t.start()
    #  time.sleep(0.5)
    input("blocking...")
```

I expected: 0 1 2 and etc. But i get blocking...

Update:
Works in the console. If you run it through Pycharm windows, the proccess is blocked.
[settings_pycharm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3itLn.png)

Comment: After adding `import multiprocessing, time` to the top of the file, and running it (in Alpine Linux, using `python3 testmp.py`), I see the first line with `blocking...0` appear instantly, and subsequent lines (`1`, `2`, etc.) appear every second. Are you not seeing that? Your description of the problem is not very clear.

Comment: The only change when uncommenting the `time.sleep(0.5)` is that the `blocking...` appears on the second line, before the `1`, exactly as I'd expect. And I've tested it on both Windows with `cmd.exe` and in `bash` on Alpine Linux, and the behavior is the same on both with the `time.sleep(0.5)` commented out, and changes in the same way on both when it's uncommented.

Comment: Your comments/edits are diametrically opposite.  One one hand, you stated you were expecting 0 1 2 but in the screenshot, it's blocking.  Which one is it?

Comment: This a duplicate of [input() function prevents new multiprocessing process to start when run through PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56456695/364696) and probably many other such questions, for all of which, the simple answer is "IDE terminal windows are a horrific kludge that breaks down in the face of the *other* horrific kludges involved in implementing `multiprocessing` in the first place; use an actual terminal, not the IDE".

Comment: Another duplicate: [input() function breaks Process invocation in Python with multiprocessing module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77120424/364696). And more on the problems in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47267077/364696).

Comment: Ah, and finally a duplicate with an accepted answer covering the basic issue: [Python multiprocessing code can only be run in terminal or debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76921865/364696). Can someone close this as a dupe? (I burned my gold badge powers when I retracted my "close as not-reproducible" vote, before the OP mentioned PyCharm)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you forgot to join:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def add(counter):
    while 1:
        print(counter.value)
        counter.value += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=add, args=(counter,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    input("blocking...")
```

Comment: The `join` prevents the `blocking...` from ever occurring, but it wouldn't change whether or nor the digits appear, and I *think* the OP is saying they don't see digits appearing.

Comment: Running the poster's code, as is, resulted in failure.  Adding the `join()` method gives the poster the result they were asking ==> "I expected: 0 1 2 and etc. But i get blocking...".

Comment: How did you run it? Cause I ran it myself and saw the initial `blocking...` followed by the digits regularly appearing. It's possible it's a difference between forking and spawning (which differ by OS), but I see no obvious reason for the `.join` to change anything. *Update*: Tried it in Windows `cmd.exe` as well, and it behave the same as it did on Alpine Linux. And both work with `time.sleep(0.5)` uncommented as well.

Comment: On MacOS so you're assumption between forking/spawning is correct.  I've always known to use `join()` as a best practice method, muscle memory and what not.

Comment: Huh. That's... odd. Windows and modern-Python-on-macOS both use spawn, old-Python-on-macOS and Linux use fork, and I can't reproduce on either Windows or Linux. `join`ing is good to do at some point, but if the `blocking...` is supposed to be seen, you'd need to `join` after the `input` call, because that child process never finishes, so the `input` call is thoroughly pointless if you `join` first.

Comment: Agree with your comments but I'm assuming that the poster put the `blocking` in as a means of debugging.